# Readiness probe warning: Probe terminated redirects, Response body:

Tags: kubernetes, healthcheck

an HTTP healthcheck with Healthcheck.
As you can see, it is redirected to the outside.

```
root@wordpress-848c85d8d6-8cb15:/#
curl
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
http://10.42.3.26 -I
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2024 14:24:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.16
X-Redirect-By: Wordpress
Location: https://colal6.app/.
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

As far as I know, if target is on the same host, healthcheck should follow the redirection.
if it has a different host, it doesn't follow and treats it as success.

However, I am getting the following error
`Readiness probe warning: Probe terminated redirects, Response body:`

I don't know why it is being followed if the host is different.